# React application, can't get data in Postman from mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, postman

I was following this tutorial on the internet to make my application in react https://youtu.be/x4dIga_3S4I and at 1:06 am I get stuck with the postman request "http://localhost:8080/api/products-by-categories" since I get this "{
"data" : []
}" I've modified my code for the database connection part, so I'm able to connect and create the data, but I can't retrieve the data I created on postman.

Here's my index.js server:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const db = require('./db');

const app = express();
const productRouter = require('./routes/productRouter');
const userRouter = require('./routes/productRouter');

const Order = require('./models/orderModel');

const env = require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}

const calculateOrderAmount = (orderItems) => {
    const initialValue = 0;
    const itemsPrice = orderItems.reduce(
        (previousValue, currentValue) =>
        previousValue + currentValue.price * currentValue.amount, initialValue
    );
    return itemsPrice * 100;
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(
  express.json({
    // We need the raw body to verify webhook signatures.
    // Let's compute it only when hitting the Stripe webhook endpoint.
    verify: function (req, res, buf) {
      if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/webhook')) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    },
  })
);

// Expose a endpoint as a webhook handler for asynchronous events.
// Configure your webhook in the stripe developer dashboard
// https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks
app.post('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
    let data, eventType;
  
    // Check if webhook signing is configured.
    if (process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
      // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
      let event;
      let signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
      try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
          req.rawBody,
          signature,
          process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
        return res.sendStatus(400);
      }
      data = event.data;
      eventType = event.type;
    } else {
      // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
      // we can retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
      data = req.body.data;
      eventType = req.body.type;
    }
  
    if (eventType === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
      // Funds have been captured
      // Fulfill any orders, e-mail receipts, etc
      // To cancel the payment after capture you will need to issue a Refund (https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds)
      console.log(' Payment captured!');
    } else if (eventType === 'payment_intent.payment_failed') {
      console.log('❌ Payment failed.');
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to Food Ordering"});
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
app.use('/api/', productRouter);
app.use('/api/', userRouter);

app.post('/create-payment-intent', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { orderItems, shippingAddress, userId } = req.body;
        console.log(shippingAddress);

        const totalPrice = calculateOrderAmount(orderItems);

        const taxPrice = 0;
        const shippingPrice = 0;

        const order = new Order({
            orderItems,
            shippingAddress,
            paymentMethod: 'stripe',
            totalPrice,
            taxPrice,
            shippingPrice,
            user: ''
        })

        // await order.save();

        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: totalPrice,
            currency: 'usd'
        })

        res.send({
            clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
        })
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: {
                message: e.message
            }
        })
    }
})
```

My productRouteur.js

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

const Product = require('../models/productModel')

router.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.find()
        res.status(200).send({ data: products})
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: err})
    }
})

router.get('/products-by-categories', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.aggregate([
            { $match: {}},
            { $group: {
                _id: '$category',
                products: { $push: '$$ROOT'}
            }},
            { $project: { name: '$_id', products: 1, _id: 0}}
        ])
        res.status(200).send({ data: products})
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: err})
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

And my productmodel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const CategorySchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true }
    }
)

const ProductSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        adjective: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: String, required: true },
        category: { type: String, required: true },
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Thank you for your help